# Adding tiles/imagery in Google Map v2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've seen the app [Lost in Campus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.studentservices.lostoncampus) which is a great app for finding a specific location in a campus. I just don't know what exactly they've used to customize their maps.

Here's the image:

[image]

What exactly was used here to customize the campus map? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tile overlays may have been used to achieve this. Check out the link below for more information!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay

Good luck!